# Facebook JavaScript SDK from browser console

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create a script for Facebook Messenger which is intended to be run from the browser console. As part of the script's functionality, I need to access the Facebook Graph - here is the relevant code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId            : '(my app's ID is here)',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v2.12'
  });


  FB.api(
    '/me?fields=name',
    'GET',
    {fields: 'name'},
    function(response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log(response);
      }
      else {
        console.log("Error with SDK!");
      }
    }
  );
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
};
```

Most of the code is copied from the Facebook help page. Unfortunately, when run, neither the request response nor the string 'Error with SDK!' are logged to the console.

I am not quite sure why this doesn't work as intended and one of my thoughts is that the code has to be executed from an actual web page - however, this is not an option since the code has to be run directly from Messenger in order to obtain its source code. This can not be done from another URL due to the Same-Origin Policy. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to _achieve_ here? Anything where you ask general users to copy&paste something into their browser console, is not going to amuse Facebook ...

Comment: @CBroe I do understand the security concerns of non-techies and their strong desire to push a single button to make everything magically work, but whether they decide to run the code is their own business. The goal of the script is to count the messages exchanged with users according to Messenger's source code and is intended mainly for my personal usage, as well as friends'. If the code is of interest to you and if it would affect the answer, it could be found here: https://github.com/Elhitch/Messenger-Messages-Count

Comment: _"since the code has to be run directly from Messenger"_ - what do you mean by that? Before you said in the browser, but not "on" any website ... so where exactly do you want to run this now? "On" facebook.com or messenger.com is something you can forget about, at least in halfway current browsers, because those sites issue CSP headers, explicitly to prevent what you are trying to do from working. And you can not just make an API request by only initializing the SDK, you need to obtain an access token first.

Comment: What I meant is, as stated on the GitHub page readme file, to run the script from the browser console on a tab that has Messenger opened - running it from anywhere else is not going to work. After testing the script on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, it seems to work fine - the only problem is that Firefox refuses to run document.write(). Thank you for your time and tips as well as the answer to the question.

Comment: So that would be running it "on" messenger.com then, in the console opened on that page. And you do not get errors with that …? If I take your script and copy&paste it to console, I get several, telling me that the CSP headers of that site prevent this kind of script execution.

Comment: Nope, I am not getting any errors except the aforementioned on Firefox - 'InvalidStateError: XMLHttpRequest has an invalid context.'. However, commenting out the document.write() functions and substituting them with alert() does print the expected output. Acquaintances who tested the code mentioned it worked fine for them too.